# Equivalence between two definitions of a category having exponential objects

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, cartesian-closed-categories

A category with products is said to *have exponentials* if for all objects $x, y$ there exists an object $y^x$ equipped with an arrow $e\colon x\times y^x\to y$ such that for all objects $z$ and all arrows $f\colon x\times z\to y$ there is a unique arrow $\bar{f}\colon z\to y^x$ satisfying $e\circ (id_x\times\bar{f})=f$.

I see that if a category has exponentials, then $f\mapsto \bar{f}$ is a natural isomorphism between $hom(x\times z, y)$ and $hom(z, y^x)$ with inverse $\bar{f}\mapsto id_x\times\bar{f}$. Hence the functor $x\times (-)$ is left adjoint to $(-)^x$.

I am wondering about the converse: if $C$ is a category with products such that $x\times (-)$ has a right adjoint, does it follow that $C$ has exponentials?

In particular, if we just assume that $x\times (-)$ has a right adjoint, how do we equip $y^x$ with the arrow $e\colon x\times y^x\to y$. Also, how do we deduce that the equation $e\circ (id_x\times\bar{f})=f$ holds precisely?

Somehow the existence of a right adjoint of $x\times (-)$ feels weaker and more abstract than the universal property definition of a category having exponentials given above.

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent ; the map $x\times y^x\to y$ is just the $y$ component of the counit, so $e\circ (id_x\times\bar{f})=f$ comes from the usual construction of the bijection in terms of unit and counit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose one needs AC to choose an object $y^x$ for each $x$ and $y$.

Accepting this, one gets the arrow $e$ from the formalism of units/counits in adjunctions.
If $F$ is a right adjoint of $x\times(-)$ then naturally,
$$\text{hom}(a,Fy)\cong\text{hom}(x\times a,y).$$
Take $a=Fy$. Then
$$\text{hom}(Fy,Fy)\cong\text{hom}(x\times Fy,y).$$
The identity on the left maps to a homomorphism $e:x\times Fy\to y$ on the right.
We are denoting $Fy$ as $y^x$, and this $e:x\times y^x\to y$ is the exponential map.